# ¿Deben eliminarse de las respuestas los consejos y opiniones que no responden a la pregunta en sí?

Tags: discusión, convenciones-sociales

Por consenso, se decidió eliminar los saludos en las publicaciones. Algo con lo que estoy de acuerdo.

Ahora, vamos al siguiente nivel: expresarnos con familiaridad, dando consejos y/u opiniones. Casi diría que de forma *paternal*:

> Espero te tomes el tiempo a leer lo sig, ya que encontré algunos errores que estas teniendo, no te preocupes, todos iniciamos así alguna vez, sigue aprendiendo que es muy interesante todo esto.

<sub>Tomado de aquí: [¿Cómo concatenar cadenas de texto y variables en C?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/332364/19610)</sub>

Mi opinión al respecto es la misma que sobre los saludos: *estorba*, añadiendo ruido a la publicación.

¿Se eliminan de la publicación o se mantienen?

Comment: El titulo es claro pero con el ejemplo me he liado... ¿Que hay de los consejos que se le dan individualmente al OP, que no responden a la pregunta pero que si le pueden ayudar a mejorar posibles carencias que tiene este a la hora de programar? Ejemplo: El OP en su código está usando `ids` en varios elementos y le adviertes de ello. Esto no responde a la pregunta pero no lo considero _ruido_. ¿Quizás se deberían de eliminar de la respuesta y ponérselo como comentario?

Comment: @x3kagainstSEbehavior nótese que el título lo cambié yo, espero no haber cambiado la esencia de la buena pregunta de Trauma (creo que no). Respondiendo a tu consulta, yo creo que es mejor moverlo a comentarios por ser algo tangencial.

Comment: @x3kagainstSEbehavior Personalmente, **no me gustan los consejos**. Una buena pregunta X tiene una respuesta exacta Z. Los consejos suelen ser sobre el *contexto*, sobre el código de un usuario concreto. Consejos que pueden confundir a otros usuarios, y ser completamente irrelevantes (*ergo*, son **ruido**) a un futuro usuario que no los necesite.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Si no están añadiendo contenido real a la publicación, yo creo que estorban.

Debemos recordar que las publicaciones no solo van dirigidas al autor de la pregunta (AP), sino a un montón de personas más que lo leerán en el futuro cuando tengan problemas similares. A estas personas probablemente les dé igual todo el contexto del proceso madurativo del AP, por lo que este contenido no aportará nada y será "paja" alrededor de la respuesta que están buscando.

También es verdad que no hace falta ir a la búsqueda de estos textos y eliminarlos en masa, sino más bien eliminarlos a medida que editemos publicaciones de forma más general para hacerlas mejores.

Comment: Je. Para una vez que me monto las respuestas para votar ... llegas tú y publicas una respuesta :-p

Comment: @Trauma ay perdona que te chafara la idea (aunque he votado) :D es que creo que el debate tiene más miga que un simple voto a favor o en contra de una propuesta :) Dejaría estas preguntas-cuestionario para temas muy concretos o cuando ya están muy masticados.

Comment: ¿ Crees que debería eliminar las `si`/`no` y dar lugar a un debate mas extenso ? No me parece mal.

Comment: @Trauma Que yo sepa los votos en Meta se pueden usar para expresar apoyo o rechazo a la idea, así que con una única respuesta ya vale para saber la opinión de la gente: si se queda en negativo es que a la gente no le atrae la idea, si se queda en positivo es que es una idea popular. Con esta respuesta ya la gente puede expresar su opinión.

Comment: @PabloLozano Listo, *arresolvido* :-)